# Windows Apache. Очистить error.log не останавливая сервер

Tags: windows, apache

Как очистить error.log не останавливая Apache на Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Unlocker. Выручал меня в похожих ситуациях пару раз.
http://www.unlocker-ru.com/

Comment: Не, не пойдет. Ну все равно спасибо за ответ, будем на убунте крутить. Закрываю вопрос

Comment: @Антон если ответ точно не решает проблему - **не стоит помечать его как принятый**.